# How to hide SORT BY PRICE and PRICE FILTER NAVIGATION LAYER for not login user in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, filtered-nav

Is it possible to hide the `Sort by Price` and `Price Filter Navigation Layer` at category product list page for users that are not logged on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Claudiu Creanga for help, I've modified his code to work perfect with my theme, i use theme puro for icotheme.

1. hide the Sort by Price

Replace this code in template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml

```
                                            <ul id="sort_by" class="sort_by collapse">
                                            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
                                                </li>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </ul>
```

with :

```
                                            <ul id="sort_by" class="sort_by collapse">
                                        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                                            <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): //not logged in, hide price ?>
                                                <?php if(strpos($this->__($_order), "Price") === false):  ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: // logged in ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
                                                </li>

                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </ul>
```

2. Hide Price Filter Navigation Layer

Replace this code in template\catalog\layer\view.phtml

```
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
```

with:

```
                <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): //not logged in, hide price ?>
                <?php if(strpos($this->__($_filter->getName()), "Price") === false):  ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php else: // logged in ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That filter is most likely in `template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml`

The code that is of interest to you is:

```
 <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?>">
                    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
```

so delete that and add something like this:

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?>">
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <?php 
            if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): //not logged in, hide price ?>

                <?php if(strpos($this->__($_order), "Price") === false):  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php else: // logged in ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
               <?php endif; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

*untested code

Comment: Thank you for help. I've little modified your code to work with my theme. And now, hide Sort by price is working! How about price filter in layared navigation ?